# WinUI 3 - custom control with content

Tags: xaml, winui-3, winui

I can't find how to easily create a custom control in which I can insert content in xaml. For example, I would like my control to contain a grid that I style somehow and then insert content into it from outside the component.

```
<local:MyComponent>
   ... some xaml content
</local:MyComponent>
```

My idea was that there was some sort of placeholder tell where to put the content. But it will probably be different.

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <ContentPlaceholder />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for the posted solutions. They all helped me get the solution I needed.

I ended up creating a separate content component as follows:

1. I added a new UserControl in Visula Studio (MyContentControl.xaml file + MyContentControl.xaml.cs is created).
2. In the file MyContentControl.xaml.cs I change the inheritance from UserControl to ContentControl.
3. In the MyContentControl.xaml file, I change the UserControl tag to ContentControl and add the ContentControl.Template tag.

MyContentControl.xaml.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace winui_3_app.components;

public sealed partial class MyContentControl : ContentControl
{
    public MyContentControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

MyContentControl.xaml

```
<ContentControl
    x:Class="winui_3_app.components.MyContentControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:winui_3_app.components"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
            // Content decoration
            <Grid Background="Yellow" Padding="10, 10, 10, 10">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
    // Content placeholder
    <ContentControl.Content />
</ContentControl>
```

Using a component

```xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="winui_3_app.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:local="using:winui_3_app.components"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <local:MyContentControl>
            // Some content
            <TextBlock>Hello!</TextBlock>
        </local:MyContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me show you two examples:

**Example A**

Create a custom control and add a `DependencyProperty` for your content. You also need to add the `ContentProperty` attribute so you can set the content in XAML.

CustomControl.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup;

namespace CustomContentControlExample;

[ContentProperty(Name = "Content")]
public sealed class CustomControl : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Content),
            typeof(object),
            typeof(CustomControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public CustomControl()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomControl);
    }

    public object Content
    {
        get => GetValue(ContentProperty);
        set => SetValue(ContentProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Generic.xaml

```xml
<Style TargetType="local:CustomControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomControl">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Example B**

Create a custom control that inherits from `ContentControl`.

CustomContentControl.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace CustomContentControlExample;

public sealed class CustomContentControl : ContentControl
{
    public CustomContentControl()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomContentControl);
    }
}
```

Generic.xaml

```xml
<Style TargetType="local:CustomContentControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomContentControl">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to have the `Style` in *Generic.xaml*, you can create a `ResourceDictionary` file:

CustomContentControl.xaml

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CustomContentControlExample">

    <Style TargetType="local:CustomControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomControl">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

and add the `ResourceDictionary` in *Generic.xaml* or in *App.xaml*:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="CustomControl.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample, everything works great. Is it possible to have the xaml code from Generic.xaml in a special file that is bound to the .cs file of the component? My point is that the component does not have part of the code in the global file and is thus separated.

Comment: Update my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and suggestions. I found a solution that works for me (see last post). Hopefully this solution is correct.

Answer (score 2):

There is already such a control. It's called `ContentControl`. It has a `Content` property that you can set to any XAML content. You can then use the `Template` property to define a `ControlTemplate` with the surrounding `Grid`, e.g.:

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Grid Background="Yellow">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
    <ContentControl.Content>
        <!-- Some XAML content: -->
        <TextBlock>some content...</TextBlock>
    </ContentControl.Content>
</ContentControl>
```

To be able to reuse the `ContentTemplate`, you can store it as a resource in a resource dictionary. For example in `App.xaml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application
    x:Class="App1.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
                <!-- Other merged dictionaries here -->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="gridTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Grid Background="Yellow">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Usage:**

```
<ContentControl Template="{StaticResource gridTemplate}">
    <!-- Some XAML content: -->
    <TextBlock>some content...</TextBlock>
</ContentControl>
```

You can also set the `Content` property to any object and use the `ContentTemplate` property to define the appearance for this object.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works beautifully. Is it possible to use a ContentControl to create a custom component instead of a UserControl? I would like to have a component that has adjustable content and also has some C# code. As is the case when I create a custom Control (xaml + .cs code).

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you could create a custom class that inherits from `ContentControl` and then add any custom to it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and suggestions. I found a solution that works for me (see last post). Hopefully this solution is correct.